# Displaying opencv image using python flask after taking input from user and use mouse events after displaying of that image

Tags: javascript, python, flask, web

I am able to print my code on using imshow in opencv but unable to print it on ui using flask
Is there any way to do it someone please help me out..
I wanted to use mouse events after displaying it in flask api
file1.py

```
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from imutils import perspective
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import imutils
import cv2
import csv
from csv import writer

lval = \[\]

def rescaleFrame(frame, scale=0.48):
width = int(frame.shape\[1\] \* scale)
height = int(frame.shape\[0\] \* scale)
dimensions = (width, height)
return cv2.resize(frame, dimensions, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

def midpoint(ptA, ptB):
return ((ptA\[0\] + ptB\[0\]) \* 0.5, (ptA\[1\] + ptB\[1\]) \* 0.5)

image = cv2.imread("leg1.jpeg")
image = rescaleFrame(image)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)

edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 100)
edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=1)
edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=1)

# find contours in the edge map

cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

# sort the contours from left-to-right and initialize the

# 'pixels per metric' calibration variable

(cnts, \_) = contours.sort_contours(cnts)
pixelsPerMetric = None

def click_event(event, x, y, flags, param):
if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
box1 = \[\]
cv2.circle(orig, (x, y), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
points.append((x, y))
if len(points) % 2 !=0:
qx = x
qy = y
cv2.line(orig, (qx, qy), (qx + 500, qy), (224, 224, 224), 1)
cv2.line(orig, (qx, qy), (qx, qy + 500), (224, 224, 224), 1)
cv2.line(orig, (qx, qy), (qx, qy - 500), (224, 224, 224), 1)
cv2.line(orig, (qx, qy), (qx - 500, qy), (224, 224, 224), 1)
if len(points) % 2 == 0:
cv2.line(orig, points\[-1\], points\[-2\], (255, 0, 0), 1)
box1.append(points\[-1\])
box1.append(points\[-2\])
first, last = box1\[0\], box1\[1\]
first1, last1 = midpoint(first, last)
\# cv2.circle(orig, (int(first), int(last)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
dA = dist.euclidean((first\[0\], first\[1\]), (last\[0\], last\[1\]))
dimA = round((dA / pixelsPerMetric),3)
\# copying the values from image to csv file
lval.append(dimA)
file = open('value.csv', 'a')
file.truncate(0)
writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(lval)
cv2.putText(orig, "{:.1f}in".format(dimA), (int(first\[0\] - 15), int(first\[1\] - 10)),
cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.65, (255, 255, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow('image1', orig)

# loop over the contours individually

for c in cnts:
\# if the contour is not sufficiently large, ignore it
if cv2.contourArea(c) \< 100:
continue
\# compute the rotated bounding box of the contour
orig = image.copy()
box = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)
box = np.array(box, dtype="int")
\# order the points in the contour such that they appear
\# in top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left
\# order, then draw the outline of the rotated bounding box
box = perspective.order_points(box)
cv2.drawContours(orig, \[box.astype("int")\], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
\# loop over the original points and draw them
for (x, y) in box:
cv2.circle(orig, (int(x), int(y)), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
\# unpack the ordered bounding box, then compute the midpoint
\# between the top-left and top-right coordinates, followed by
\# the midpoint between bottom-left and bottom-right coordinates
(tl, tr, br, bl) = box
(tltrX, tltrY) = midpoint(tl, tr)
(blbrX, blbrY) = midpoint(bl, br)

    # compute the midpoint between the top-left and top-right points,
    # followed by the midpoint between the top-right and bottom-right
    (tlblX, tlblY) = midpoint(tl, bl)
    (trbrX, trbrY) = midpoint(tr, br)
    
    # draw the midpoints on the image
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(tltrX), int(tltrY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(blbrX), int(blbrY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(tlblX), int(tlblY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(trbrX), int(trbrY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    # draw lines between the midpoints
    cv2.line(orig, (int(tltrX), int(tltrY)), (int(blbrX), int(blbrY)),
             (255, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.line(orig, (int(tlblX), int(tlblY)), (int(trbrX), int(trbrY)),
             (255, 0, 255), 2)
    # compute the Euclidean distance between the midpoints
    dA = dist.euclidean((tltrX, tltrY), (blbrX, blbrY))
    dB = dist.euclidean((tlblX, tlblY), (trbrX, trbrY))
    # if the pixels per metric has not been initialized, then
    # compute it as the ratio of pixels to supplied metric
    # (in this case, inches)
    if pixelsPerMetric is None:
        pixelsPerMetric = dA / 0.866 #args["width"]
        cv2.imshow('image1', orig)
        # compute the size of the object
        dimA = dA / pixelsPerMetric
        dimB = dB / pixelsPerMetric
    
        # draw the object sizes on the image
        cv2.putText(orig, "{:.1f}in".format(dimA),
                    (int(tltrX - 15), int(tltrY - 10)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    0.65, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(orig, "{:.1f}in".format(dimB),
                    (int(trbrX + 10), int(trbrY)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    0.65, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.imshow('image1',orig)
    else:
        cv2.setMouseCallback('image1', click_event)
        break

orig = image.copy()

cv2.imshow('image1', orig)
points = \[\]
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the python file that I want it to be displayed on the website using flask but unable to do it.
I even tried mouse events using javascript but also unable to do that dynamically as I did in python file someone please help me out with this`

Comment: Try to copy/write the image to an applicable image format (i.e. jpg, png, tiff, etc.), store it on a site static folder then have it available to display.

Comment: [tour], [ask], [mre]. your code is entirely broken. proof-read before abandoning your question.